# (libcups2) dependency hell after apt upgrade

Tags: release-loki, updates, desktop, apt, dependencies

Some broken packages have been shipped in mainline. Package libcups2 has broken apt completely after an upgrade.

When I try **apt -f install** the package manager suggests to remove a whole batch of packages, including *elementary-desktop*

apt upgrade provides the following dependency errors

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 cups-bsd : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 cups-client : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 cups-core-drivers : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 cups-daemon : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 libcups2-dev : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 libcupscgi1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 libcupsimage2 : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 libcupsmime1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
 libcupsppdc1 : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2) but 2.1.3-4 is installed
```

I have tried manually installing the debs with version ubuntu0.2, but it hasn't helped.

Trying to apt remove or purge the cups-related packages trows an even longer list of dependencies. Same with using aptitude or apt-get.

dpkg --reconfigure -a trows these dependency errors

```
Errors were encountered while processing:  libcups2-dev:amd64 
cups-daemon 
cups-core-drivers
```

Trying to remove the packages brings me back to the same error as above with the libcups2 errors.

What to do? I assume I can't just accept that apt -f upgrade removes elementary-desktop because it would break the whole desktop environment?

Comment: What is mainline? Do you mean elementary-daily ?

Comment: The bug was in ubuntu xenial mainline, it has appeared on ubuntu and linux mint too, without the affected elementary-desktop and other dependency issues.

Comment: Did you install elementary from a live CD or did you just install elementary-desktop over Ubuntu/linux mint?

For me your issue looks like 2 ppas with different packages are colliding. You have to delete one of those. Or you can also install those missing packages.. like `cups-daemon`

Comment: Installing the packages manually didn't work, only the original elementary repositories were enabled - from a clean eOS install.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your input, I found the fix. Add

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

to the /etc/apt/sources.list, and apt upgrade -f automatically resolves the issue.